# advice with pointers in matlab

Tags: matlab, pointers, memory

I am running a very large meta-simulation where I go through two hyperparameters (lets say x and y) and for each set of hyperparameters (x_i & y_j) I run a modest sized subsimulation. Thus:

```
for x=1:I
    for y=1:j
        subsimulation(x,y)
    end
end
```

For each subsimulation however, about 50% of the data is common to every other subsimulation, or subsimulation(x_1,y_1).commondata=subsimulation(x_2,y_2).commondata.

This is very relevant since so far the total simulation results file size is ~10Gb! Obviously, I want to save the common subsimulation data 1 time to save space. However, the obvious solution, being to save it in one place would screw up my plotting function, since it directly calls subsimulation(x,y).commondata.

I was wondering whether I could do something like 
subsimulation(x,y).commondata=% pointer to 1 location in memory %

If that cant work, what about this less elegant solution:

```
subsimulation(x,y).commondata='variable name' %string
```

and then adding

```
if(~isstruct(subsimulation(x,y).commondata)), 
    subsimulation(x,y).commondata=eval(subsimulation(x,y).commondata)
end
```

What solution do you guys think is best?

Thanks
DankMasterDan

Comment: As long as you do not modify `subsimulation(x,y).commondata`, the data is not copied.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this fairly easily by defining a [handle class](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_oop/comparing-handle-and-value-classes.html). See also [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/handle-classes.html).

An example:

```
classdef SimulationCommonData < handle
    properties
        someData
    end

    methods
        function this = SimulationCommonData(someData)
            % Constructor
            this.someData = someData;
        end
    end
end
```

Then use like this,

```
commonData = SimulationCommonData(something);
subsimulation(x, y).commondata = commonData;
subsimulation(x, y+1).commondata = commonData; 
% These now point to the same reference (handle)
```

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment, as long as you do not modify the `common` data, you can pass it as third input and still not copy the array in memory on each iteration (a very good read is [Internal Matlab memory optimizations](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/internal-matlab-memory-optimizations/)). This image will clarify:

[image]

As you can see, the first jump in memory is due to the creation of `common` and the second one to the allocation of the output `c`. If the data were copied on each iteration, you would have seen many more memory fluctuations. For instance, a third jump, then a decrease, then back up again and so on...

Follows the code (I added a `pause` in between each iteration to make it clearer that no big jumps occur during the loop):

```
function out = foo(a,b,common)
out = a+b+common;
end

for ii = 1:10; c = foo(ii,ii+1,common); pause(2); end
```